# Replicate data.frame using vector length & pass each element as a new column

Tags: r

I have a data frame `dd` and a vector `vec`. I want to multiply the dataframe as many times as is the length of the vector. Also, I want to add this vector element as a new column to the dataframe.

```
# Dummy data
dd<- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5))
vec <- c("a", "b", "d")
```

Desired output:

```
  id vec
1  1 a
2  2 a
3  3 a
4  4 a
5  5 a
6  1 b
7  2 b
8  3 b
9  4 b
10 5 b
11 1 d
12 2 d
13 3 d
14 4 d
15 5 d
```

Originally, I would get the `length(vec)`, use `rep(vec, each = length(vec))` and then add this column to `rbind(dd, dd,dd)`. But, if need to replicate `dd` twenty times, how to do this in a smarter way?

Comment: You seem to be looking for `?expand.grid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `crossing`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(dd, vec)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
vec <- data.frame(vec)
merge(dd,vec)
```

Output:

```
   id vec
1   1   a
2   2   a
3   3   a
4   4   a
5   5   a
6   1   b
7   2   b
8   3   b
9   4   b
10  5   b
11  1   d
12  2   d
13  3   d
14  4   d
15  5   d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `rep` like below

```
transform(
  dd,
  vec = rep(vec, each = length(id))
)
```

which gives

```
   id vec
1   1   a
2   2   a
3   3   a
4   4   a
5   5   a
6   1   b
7   2   b
8   3   b
9   4   b
10  5   b
11  1   d
12  2   d
13  3   d
14  4   d
15  5   d
```